# Remove selected API results before displaying in Table View

Tags: xcode, json, uitableview, restkit

I'm working with data from an API using RestKit.

I want to get a list of businesses, and am getting that back correctly. Yet, once I get that list, on my end **I need to remove out any business** that is a "McDonalds" **before I display the results** in a `UITableView`.

Example Response:

```
"venue": [{
    "name": "X Business", {
```

There is no way to remove these results before the API response, Is there some way to do this once I get the API response back but before I display results in the `UITableView`?

**EDIT:**

View Controller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *springs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *leafs;


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];  // 13 objects
        Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // 30 objects

        cell.textLabel.text = leaf.shortName;
        return cell;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**
Response.m is the model

```
@implementation Response

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"premium", @"premium",
         nil];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}

@end
```

Comment: You always have the control of when you want to display the result in a table view. You can filter the data on your end before calling the table view reload data, as an example.

Comment: @verbumdei Thanks for the response!  Yeah I know its possible, but I just couldn't figure out how I would go about doing it.  Do I create another dictionary from the response, or whats the best way to go about doing it?

Comment: How do you currently set the data source for the table view? Are you using NSArray? Can you post some codes on how you set this data source property?

Comment: @verbumdei sure, I added some code in the edit.  I'm using RestKit mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit can perform validation of incoming data using KVC, so you can filter the incoming data during mapping (you will save time and effort during mapping and not have to deal with post processing the result).

Check the documentation [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation, I'll check to see if the KVC helps me out here!

Comment: Would I put this KVC code in my Model Class I built for `Spring` and `Leaf`, or would it go in the `viewDidLoad` of my View Controller?

Comment: The validation methods must be in the model classes.

Comment: I updated my question to show the model class, would it go as a separate set of lines after the `+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping` has already been done?

Comment: Yes, it's a new method in the Response model class. The documentation shows the methods and sample implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just filter the array you get from the API with NSPredicate, for example if each object, e.g. Spring in your case, inside the array has businessName property:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"businessName = %@", @"McDonalds"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.springs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: And then just use `*filteredArray` instead of where I'm using `spring.leafs` above?

Comment: @Reez yeah, if that is what you need :)